# separating-front-end-and-api for jhipster

Tags: jhipster

Does anyone have any idea, why these [three points](https://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/) are introduced and how we can implement this if we decide to separately deploy spring boot and SPA?

- Calls to / serve static assets (from the front-end), which should not
  be cached by the browser.
- Calls to /app (which contains the
  client-side application) and to /content (which contains the static
  content, like images and CSS) should be cached in production, as
  those assets are hashed.
- Calls to a non-existant route should forward
  the request to index.html. This is normally handled in the backend
  through ClientForwardController.

Answer (score 1):

They explain how you should handle the HTTP requests that point to the static parts.

2 first points may be configured in your reverse proxy for example.
Last point is a configuration of the RP but also of the router part of your js framework.